Lookup (Picklist dependency)
Our system has a Case object which has a Service field and Unit field. The Unit field is a lookup (picklist dependency) of the Service (picklist) field.
At present our agents have to use the search function to find an item in a list of over 300 units. There are approximately 30 units per Service.
I have already considered changing the Unit field to a field dependency.
Can I change the Unit field to show a drop down containing ONLY the units that are dependent on the Service field value chosen, rather than doing a search of all units? Is there a rule or flow I could use?

You can set up your Unit field to be dependent on the Service field picklist. See Salesforce documentation here.
You basically define what values in Unit should be available for selection by the user for a selected value in Service.
From the documentation they use the example of the Opportunity object where the Reason field is dependent on the Stage field.
If a user select Closed Won then they will only be able to select for the Reason:

Superior features
Lower price

where if the user selects Closed Lost then for the Reason field they will only be able to select:

Inferior features
Higher price
Company viability

To set up these dependencies:

Navigate to the Object's Fields & Relationships section
Select the Field dependencies button (where the New button is for creating new fields).
Create a new dependency
Select the controlling field and the dependent field. Just be aware some of the limitation here (standard field cannot be selected as a dependent field):



Select all the values that needs to be displayed for a given value in the controlling field:



Save and test:


Good luck!
